# Getting message as machine type other than current machine, how to fix that in MDT?

Tags: mdt

I am installing applications as part of OS task sequence in windows 10 and got below message and the installation is skipped.

[image: mdt message]

My application:

[image: application]

The OS filter is not kept, how to fix this?

Comment: Are you running a 32-bits PE? It looks like you are trying to run a 64 bits executable on a 32-bits environment

Comment: It is 64 bit PE and the machine type also 64bit .